# Iterate through a list and split into a 1d list

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to loop through a list in python and split words based on characters. I want to return a 1 dimension list as the result.

Example

```
wordlist = ['border\collie', 'dog\cat', 'horse\hound'] # slash fix
```

Expected outcome 
new_list = ['border', 'collie', 'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'hound']

Everything that Ive tried results in a 2d list.

```
def split_slash_words(text):
    new_list = []
    new_list.append([i.split("\\") for i in text])
    return new_list
```

returned a two dimensional array, and I cannot also resplit the new_list (as it is in a list type)

Comment: `.split()` returns a list so it's only normal that the output list is a two dimensional list.

Comment: Almost there - change `append` to `extend`

Comment: strictly speaking, this is not a dupe

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
wordlist = ['border/collie', 'dog\cat', 'horse/hound']

out = []
for item in wordlist:
    for element in re.findall('\w+', item):
        out.append(element)
```

**Output:**

```
['border', 'collie', 'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'hound']
```

Comment: This might raise an IndexError exception

Comment: @MohammadJafari now will not

Answer (score 3):

The append method adds a list to the end of new_list. If you use the extend method, each item is added to new_list.

Comment: This is the answer. !!